# Code Contracts: Ensure unproven on string method

Tags: c#, code-contracts, specifications

I'm playing around with code contracts and got a simple method inserting a given count of space characters between each character.

e.g.

```
Hello -> H e l l o
World -> W   o   r   l   d
```

The method InsertSpaceBetweenLetters is implemented within a class that offers some string-property S, the string that should be returned after modification. Here's the code

```
public string InsertSpaceBetweenLetters(int spaceWidth)
{
    Contract.Requires(spaceWidth > 0);
    Contract.Requires(S.Length > 0);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() != null);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>().Length == S.Length + (S.Length - 1) * spaceWidth);

    string result = String.Empty;

    Contract.Assume(S.Length >= 0);
    for(int i = 0; i < S.Length; i++)
    {
        result += S[i];
        if (i < S.Length - 1)
            result += new String(' ', spaceWidth);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The static checker gives me the following warning:

```
ensures unproven: Contract.Result<string>().Length == S.Length + (S.Length - 1) * spaceWidth
```

I thought I could get rid of this warning with the assumption I'm doing before the loop:

```
Contract.Assume(S.Length >= 0);
```

But the warning is still there. What assumptions have to be made to get rid of the warning?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, I think you're asking too much of the static checker in this case. It would be pretty impressive if it really *could* work that out. In this case I think you'll just have to live with it being an execution-time check rather than a compile-time check.

I don't know if there's a specific way of saying "please ensure this as a post-condition, but don't try to prove it" - calling `Contract.Assume` *with the post-condition* at the end of the method *may* do it, but it would probably mean evaluating it twice :(

(As an aside, your implementation is currently *really* inefficient. That's not the topic of this question, but is still worth looking at.)

Comment: I know it is inefficient, it was a quick'n'dirty test. The string instantiation should be outside the loop. :-) I know the static checker cannot prove algorithms, that should violate some statements of theoretical cs. But I wanted to know: how many things I have to assume, to get the static checker working in this case? I just want to get a feeling about its limits

Comment: @mbue: That's for starters... then there's avoiding repeated string concatenation...

Comment: @mbue: I don't know how much you'll need to assume, and it will change over time. You *could* try extracting the string constructor call, making an assumption on the length of the string, and see whether it "knows" enough about the rest...

Answer (score 1):

I think your assumption is wrong. It doesn't hold for `S.Length == 0`: in the second `ensures` you would get a negativ value.

Second, it's not trivial to check your `ensures` statement on compile time. Probably just not implemented in the checker..

Maybe you could implement your loop differently. Remove your `if` statement and loop from 0 to S.Length-2. But I'm not sure..

Comment: The S.Length == 0 case cannot occure, because of Contract.Requires(S.Length > 0);

Comment: Can you explain this? The PRE-condition tells: S.Length > 0. That means, if we reach the assumption, S.Length is greather than 0. This implies that S.Length is >= 0.

Comment: Ah I see, I interpret it like this: you can rewrite it as `Assert(S.Length >=0);` this is certainly true. But I don't think it helps the checker if he can assume the length is 0. Because in this case the ensures statement is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        public string InsertSpaceBetweenLetters(string S, int spaceWidth) {

        Contract.Requires(spaceWidth > 0);
        Contract.Requires(S != null);
        Contract.Requires(S.Length > 0);
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() != null);
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>().Length == S.Length + (S.Length - 1) * spaceWidth);

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(String.Empty);

        int count = 0;
        int final = S.Length - 1;
        foreach ( char c in S )
        {
            result.Append(c, 1);
            if ( count < final )
            {
                result.Append(' ', spaceWidth);
            }
            ++count;
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
```